# Virtual CheckedListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, virtual, checkedlistbox

I have a datagrid that I would like to provide Excel 2007 like filtering capability for. When the user right-clicks on a column header, a menu will pop up with a list of distinct values for that column which check boxes next to each item to filter on.

The problem I am having is for columns with high cardinality, I have to add a large quantity of items to the CheckedListBox, which takes a long time to add each item to it's collection.

Is there any way to make the current winforms CheckedListBox behave in a virtual manner similar to that of a DataGridView?

If not, can anyone point me in a direction of how to create a virtual-panel type control that can fire some sort of Row/Cell painting or CellValue needed type of event?

Comment: I am not sure how you are populating the check box list, but have you considered returning the distinct list for the columns in question to a separate table in your data set and binding the whole table to the check box list directly, rather than adding them one at a time?

Comment: My data is stored in an array of objects, not a dataset

Comment: The CheckedListBox can easily handle a "large quantity of items".  If you have tens of thousands of checkable items, how would that be useful to the user?  It "sounds" like you are trying to solve one problem by introducing another.

Comment: I am going to limit the # of items to 5,000 and under, but the performance is not what I want. After having to get the distinct list of items to display, an extra .5-1 second to add the items to the listbox is not acceptable.